# angularjs typerror when upgrading to 1.3.15

Tags: angularjs

I just tried updating my angular version from `1.3.0-rc.4` to `1.3.15`, but I'm now seeing the following error on my pages:

File header containing version information:

```
/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.3.15
 * (c) 2010-2014 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */
```

Error:

```
TypeError: result.headers is not a function↵    at resolvePromiseWithResult
(http://.../js/angular.js:9720:71)↵    at processQueue 
(http://.../js/angular.js:13248:27)↵    at
http://.../js/angular.js:13264:27↵    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval
(http://.../js/angular.js:14466:28)↵    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest
(http://.../js/angular.js:14282:31)↵    at 
http://.../js/angular.js:14505:26↵    at completeOutstandingRequest 
(http://.../js/angular.js:4924:10)↵    at 
http://.../js/angular.min.js:5312:7
```

If I look at the data stored in result I see that it's an `Object` with properties `data` and `status`, where `data` contains the response of a request and `status` is the http status code. I know that one of the requests triggering this error is doing a simple `$http.get(url)` call.

Is there something I need to do to support the latest version?

Comment: Can you share some code with us? Where is this dying?

Comment: The entire call stack is what I posted, which is all I have to work on. Given the value of ``result`` when I set a breakpoint at line ``9720``, I can tell that at least one place that's generating this is calling ``$http.get(url).then(function (response) { ... });``.

Comment: Do you have any `$http` interceptors or request/response transformation logic in this app that could be causing issue?

Comment: I do, however I tried commenting them out and the errors remained. One thing I did notice is that the response at the point of the interceptors does in fact have the header function.

Comment: well according to your errors, thats the cause of your problem. If you don't end up solving it sooner, share all code within this request along with this `result.headers` thing

Comment: I just resolved it. It's tied to my template caching, with the fix mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/3354046#comment-1325030). Thank you for asking the right questions to help me narrow my focus and track this down!

Comment: awesome dude! and np